# Crosslist WebID to Site Name

Tags: data-view-web-part, cross-list

Anybody know how to take the webId in a DVWP crosslist and group the results based on webId, but instead of showing WebId show the Site Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Project Properties to display information about the lis. In this case you would want

`<ProjectProperty Name="Title"/>`

See my blog post [Project and List Properties Available from CAML](http://sympmarc.com/2009/02/26/10065/).

Comment: Ok, so I added this to my CAML Viewfields, but now when I go into the "sort & group" section within SPD, there still is not an option to group by "project title", any thoughts

Comment: SPD may not be "aware" orf those properties. When I use them, I'm usually rolling my own XSL.